# How to get the file extension in PHP?

Tags: php, file-extension

I wish to get the file extension of an image I am uploading, but I just get an array back.

```
$userfile_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$userfile_extn = explode(".", strtolower($_FILES['image']['name']));
```

Is there a way to just get the extension itself?

Answer (score 1320, accepted):

No need to use string functions. You can use something that's actually designed for what you want: [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: $path = $_FILES['image']['name'][0]; the actual file name is in an array. pathinfo will only evaluate a string.

Comment: @foureight84: That's only the case if you have upload fields named `image[]`...

Comment: I kinda modified your code a little and made a function, in case someone wants to use a function. Here is the code:function   getFileExtension($path) {
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    return $ext;
}

Comment: @ThiefMaster this returns only the FIRST extension though. In the case of images this may not be relevant, but when someone's uploading an archive it could be .tar.gz or something...

Comment: @user1914292 I don't see how that is relevant, you should always modify code for own use instead of just copying it and expecting it to work. so if you are expecting archived files instead of images you should make your code work with that too (and not just copy this answer and expect it to work for you)

Comment: This method returns GET parameters as well....

Answer (score 67):

This will work as well:

```
$array = explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']);
$extension = end($array);
```

Comment: 'Only variables should be passed by reference', the PHP Manual

Comment: This is not a good approach since the `end` function is intended to move the internal pointer of an array to the end of the array and return that element.  The problem is that the array is passed by reference and since your array is dynamically generated, it cannot be passed by reference, hence the warning or failure, depending on your version of PHP.

Comment: **Important Note**: This will fail with paths like: `/var/www/website.com/somefile` (you're better off using pathinfo).

Comment: This will fail when you changed a file extention on Windows from 
.png to .jpg. Under water it will always be a .png.

Answer (score 37):

A better method is using strrpos + substr (faster than explode for that) :

```
$userfile_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$userfile_extn = substr($userfile_name, strrpos($userfile_name, '.')+1);
```

But, to check the type of a file, using mime_content_type is a better way :
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: Better than `pathinfo()`? I don't think so.

Comment: Better than explode ;-). But, you are right, pathinfo is a better way when enabled (some mutualised server disable this function...).

Comment: **Important Note**: This will fail with paths like: `/var/www/website.com/somefile`.

Comment: This will fail where a filename has a '.' in it that occurs before the final . that separates the actual file extension. You'd be surprised at what filenames are out there that have multiple '.'

Comment: `mime_content_type` is deprecated in current PHP Version.

Comment: better than other. works for me as well.

Comment: strrpos can return FALSE

Comment: How is this compared to just using a basic regex expression?

Answer (score 24):

You could try with this for mime type

```
$image = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

`$image['mime']` will return the mime type.

This function doesn't require GD library. You can find the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

This returns the mime type of the image.

Some people use the `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` but it's not reliable as been given by the browser and not by PHP.

You can use `pathinfo()` as ThiefMaster suggested to retrieve the image extension.

First make sure that the image is being uploaded successfully while in development before performing any operations with the image.

Answer (score 12):

How about

```
$ext = array_pop($userfile_extn);
```

Comment: I don't recommend this. You are relying on the order of the array being the same years from now. It's a lazy solution that will most likely cause issues in the future.