# How to separate a string and store in two variables in PHP

Tags: php

I have string `$ab="Hello_world.wav"`, and I want store this string in two variables. One is `$a="Hello_world"` and the other `$b=".wav"`. 
How should I use a string function to get it like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368217/php-get-file-extension

Comment: What is the desired output if the file name contains additional dots?

Comment: See also [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo), [`list`](http://php.net/list), [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split), and other such pages in the quite informative PHP manual.

Comment: if you know tell answer don't put down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `preg_split()`:

```
$ab="Hello_world.wav";
$matches = preg_split('/\./', $ab);
$a = isset($matches[0]) ? $matches[0] : '';
$b = isset($matches[1]) ? '.' . $matches[1] : '';
// Print if you want by uncommenting the next line
// print $a . ' ' . $b;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
$info = pathinfo('Hello_world.wav');

var_dump($info);
```

Which gives you:

```
array (size=4)
  'dirname' => string '.' (length=1)
  'basename' => string 'Hello_world.wav' (length=15)
  'extension' => string 'wav' (length=3)
  'filename' => string 'Hello_world' (length=11)
```

So:

```
$a = $info['filename'];
$b = '.' . $info['extension'];
```

Comment: Why downvote? It seems it's the best solution (I've commented that before)

Comment: +1 for using correct function

Comment: @jerdiggity It works with string - not existing file. I've tested it without fil in my filesystem.

Comment: LOL yeah... I realized I said that in the wrong context so I deleted my comment. But yes you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Split is DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. You shouldn't use it [(PHP manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php). Instead, use `explode`:

```
$new_str_arr = explode('.', $ab);
$a = $new_str_arr[0];
$b = '.' . $new_str_arr[1];
```