# strripos array of needles inside a parent foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, strpos

I'm inside a foreach loop from a scandir() wheres the directory files are `$files as $file`. I'm trying to simplify my strripos filetype exclusions by using an array of needles, rather than passing several strripos lines for each filetype.

This works:

```
if ($code !== 'yes'){
    $excluded = strripos($file, '.js')
                || strripos($file, '.pl')
                || strripos($file, '.py')
                || strripos($file, '.py')
                || strripos($file, '.rb')
                || strripos($file, '.css')
                || strripos($file, '.php')
                || etc.;
    } else {
        $excluded = '';
    }
```

But this does not:

```
    if ($code !== 'yes'){
        $exclusions = array('.js, .pl, .py, .rb, .css, .php, etc.');
        foreach($exclusions as $exclude){
            $excluded = strripos($file, $exclude);   
        } 
    } else {
        $excluded = '';
    }
```

`$code` is a shortcode attribute defined by the user as 'yes' or anything else = no.

Then when I get to the output, I check if `$excluded` has been defined as 'yes.' Like I said, it works with the first example, but I can't get an array to work. To reiterate, I'm already inside the `$file` loop from the `scandir()`.

**UPDATE**

Tried using `in_array` but I'm probably doing something wrong. I've tried:

```
$exclusions = array('.js', '.pl', '.py', '.rb', '.css', '.php', '.htm', '.cgi', '.asp', '.cfm', '.cpp', '.dat', '.yml', '.shtm', '.java', '.class');
$excluded = strripos($file, (in_array($exclusions)));
```

And I've tried:

```
$excluded = strripos($file, (in_array('.js', '.pl', '.py', '.rb', '.css', '.php', '.htm', '.cgi', '.asp', '.cfm', '.cpp', '.dat', '.yml', '.shtm', '.java', '.class')));
```

No go.

Comment: You're messing up the curly braces, if you indent code properly you'll see what's going on.

Comment: It's correct in my actual code, just messed it up reproducing it here. Fixed here.

Comment: Try `in_array` instead of looping.

Comment: Also, your array only has one item, at least on the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried using in array but it's not working either. I'm probably doing it wrong. I'll update the post with what I've tried.

Comment: Have you tried using `glob`? You can pattern match anything.

Comment: Never used that before. Will look it up.

Comment: `in_array` doesn't return a string, are you sure you're doing it right? From the manual on `strripos` -- _if needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character._ -- Is that what you want? Where's your `in_array` needle? How are you debugging your code?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what you're suggesting that I do, is all. I've never used in_array before either.

Comment: "From the manual on strripos -- if needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character."

No, I just want to filter out the filetypes in the array. Does that mean it isn't possible to do with strripos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array currently has only one element, which is a long string:

```
'.js, .pl, .py, .rb, .css, .php, etc.'
```

You should quote each of your string elements like this:

```
$exclusions = array('.js', '.pl', '.py', '.rb', '.css', '.php', 'etc.');
```

Try changing your code to this:

```
$excluded = 'no';

if ($code !== 'yes'){
    $exclusions = array('.js', '.pl', '.py', '.rb', '.css', '.php'); 
    foreach($exclusions as $exclude){
        $check = strripos($file, $exclude); 
        if ($check !== false) {
            $excluded = 'yes';
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Start by assigning `$excluded = 'no';`. As soon as `strripos` returns anything other than `false` you assign `$excluded = 'yes';` and break out of the foreach loop. This way you end up with either 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know. :) I'll see if that fixes things.

Comment: OK. I've fixed that. Thank you. It still isn't working though.

Comment: This worked when I changed the 'no' and 'yes' values to boolean false and true. As string values, it did not output any files at all. But when I changed it to false and true, it worked as expected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, boolean is better than 'yes' or 'no', most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to check if any of the files in a particular directory has an extension in your array `$exclusions` and if it does -- exclude that file.

So, if that's what you want, then you can create a function to make `stripos` accept arrays as needles:

```
function striposa($haystack, $needle, $offset=0) {
    if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);
    foreach($needle as $query) {
        if(stripos($haystack, $query, $offset) !== false) {
            return true; // stop on first true result
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

<sup>(modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220624/1438393) answer)</sup>

---

And then, in your code, you can use it like below:

```
if ($code !== 'yes') {
    $exclusions = array('.js', '.pl', '.py', ...);
    $flag = striposa($file, $exclusions);

    if ($flag) {
        // file contains one of the extensions
    } else {
        // no matching extensions found
    }
}
```

Note that this will fail if the `$file` is something like `hi.js.foo`, but to make sure that doesn't happen, you can use `pathinfo()` to extract the extension as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368236/1438393) post.

Comment: I just now saw this answer after I accepted abstr's answer (which works well). But this is awesome. I will definitely use this. Thank you!

Comment: @Thom: Sure. Glad to have been of help.

Comment: @Thom: Nope, you cannot. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$extensions = array('js', 'pl', ...);

$extension = strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $file)));
$excluded = in_array($extension, $extensions);

if (! $excluded) {
  // do something with file
}
```

You could also use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to extract the extension.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? I updated the code, something wasn't right, but it should work now, if I understand OP correctly.

Comment: Wasn't me. I'm looking at this. Thanks for sticking with.

Comment: I tried this and returned $excluded with my shortcode and it outputs nothing.

Comment: `$excluded` is either `true` or `false`. Basically what you want is to check if the file has any of those extensions and do something if it doesn't right? Well, this is what this code does, or am I off track?. Why are you using `yes` and `no` and empty strings? Why not use booleans?

Comment: Because yes and no are values from a shortcode attribute. User defined.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to pathinfo. That's stuff I'll use as well. Thanks again.