# PHP Image resize with all types

Tags: php, image, upload, resize

I followed a tutorial on how to resize an image using PHP, thought it'd be easier than using hours trying to do it myself but i'm having a problem when uploading anything else than .jpg files which is understandable since i'm using "imagecreatefromjpeg" and "imagejpeg", but what other function can i use for all image types?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$outputDir = "../images/uploads/";
$randomInt = rand(1,1000);
$imgTmpname = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
$newImgName = $randomInt;
$imgSavedName = $randomInt . '.jpg';

move_uploaded_file($imgTmpname,$outputDir.$imgSavedName);

echo $newImgName;

$savedImgDir = $outputDir . $imgSavedName;

$imgSize = getimagesize($savedImgDir);
$imgWidth = $imgSize[0];
$imgHeight = $imgSize[1];

$newSize = ($imgWidth + $imgHeight) / ($imgWidth * ($imgHeight / 45));
$newWidth = $imgWidth * $newSize;
$newHeight = $imgHeight * $newSize;

$newImg = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
$oldImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($savedImgDir);

imagecopyresized($newImg, $oldImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $imgWidth, $imgHeight);
imagejpeg($newImg, $outputDir.$newImgName.'_thumb'.'.jpg');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the [following functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) available:

```
imagecreatefromgd2 - Create a new image from GD2 file or URL
imagecreatefromgd2part - Create a new image from a given part of GD2 file or URL
imagecreatefromgd - Create a new image from GD file or URL
imagecreatefromgif - Create a new image from file or URL
imagecreatefromjpeg - Create a new image from file or URL
imagecreatefrompng - Create a new image from file or URL
imagecreatefromstring - Create a new image from the image stream in the string
imagecreatefromwbmp - Create a new image from file or URL
imagecreatefromwebp - Create a new image from file or URL
imagecreatefromxbm - Create a new image from file or URL
imagecreatefromxpm - Create a new image from file or URL
```

Then you can choose the right one based on [the file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368217/how-to-get-the-file-extension-in-php).

Answer (score 2):

See the various functions for manipulating images at:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php