# Renaming uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, filenames, rename

I'm trying to rename the uploaded file by adding the uploader name($user)
but all it does is showing user's name in the extension part, file.jpguser, here's the code,

```
if ((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']         == 0)) {
  //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 1.4MB
  $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

 if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") &&
($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 10485760))
{

//Determine the path to which we want to save this file
  $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/affichagesimg/'.$filename'by'.$user;
  //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server


  if (!file_exists($newname)) {
    //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
    if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname)))         {

echo "<script>
alert('votre affichage a était publié avec succés !');
window.location.href='.';

</script>";
```

Comment: And what do you expect? You add `user` after extension

Comment: In ``$filename'by'.$user`` you're definitely missing a ``.``, but see @u_mulder's comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the original filename (or [use built in functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368217/how-to-get-the-file-extension-in-php)) to get the extension. for example:

```
<?php
...
$file_parts = explode('.', $uploaded_filename);
$extension = array_pop($file_parts);
$file_stub = implode('.', $file_parts);
$new_name = $file_stub . 'by' . $user . '.' . $extension;
```

Using your code, new filename is:

```
<?php
...
$new_filename = $filename . 'by' . $user . '.' . $ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function

```
$user = 'username';
$filename = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
$newname = "{$path_parts['filename']}_by_{$user}.{$path_parts['extension']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) as well to parse the file name:

$file_parts = pathinfo($uploaded_filename);

$new_name = $file_parts['filename'].'by'.$user.'.'.$file_parts['extension'];