# Failing to get file extension when using pathinfo()

Tags: php

I am building an uploader for a photo site, most of the photos that are uploaded are of type 1232132_1231231_12.jpg. when I run pathinfo() I am getting blank outputs for extension.

Here is my code

```
$target_dir = "Photos/";
$species =  filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'species');
$country =  filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'country');
$type= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'type');
include_once 'connection.php';
echo $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
for($a=0;$a<count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);$a++)
{
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$a]);
$imageFileType=pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
var_dump(pathinfo($target_file));

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" )
    {
       echo "<br> Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed. your file is a  $imageFileType <br>";
    } 
}
```

Photos/2014-02-21 18.19.08.jpg

```
 echo $target-file;
```

gives this output Photos/2014-02-21 18.19.08.jpg

for the var_dump this is echoed out to screen,
array(3) { ["dirname"]=> string(6) "Photos" ["basename"]=> string(1) "2" 
["filename"]=> string(1) "2" }

Is there something wrong with my code or does pathinfo() not work well with number and special character file names?

Is there another function that does work with these types of file names or should explode() the $target_file  with the '.' and take the last element in the returned array?

Comment: What happens if you put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script?

Comment: Please check link and read comments of marked answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368217/how-to-get-the-file-extension-in-php

Comment: What happens if you `echo "target_file=$target_file<br />\n";` right above your var_dump()? Is the filename "Photos/2" or "Photos/2.jpg"?

Comment: peter I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probleme isn't pathinfo. You're doing something weird :

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$a]);
```

This line is in a loop where $a is between 0 and...
$_FILES["file"]["name"] is returning the filename. but:

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"][0]
```

will return the first letter from the filename (2 for your example).
So, you're doing a pathinfo  on your variable :

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$a]); // looks like $target_file = Photos/2 (when $a = 0)
```

Change that line like this :

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: this has solved the problem, but i want to pass an array of photos to php and then upload them all will this mean that if i pass an array of files it wont iterate thought them?

Comment: If your input type file look like this : `<input type="file" name="file[]" id="input1" /><input type="file" name="file[]" id="input2" />`, you certainly have access to an array of files.

Answer (score 1):

For me this one worked:

```
    function convertImageToWebP($source, $destination, $quality=80) {

    if (exif_imagetype($source) == IMAGETYPE_GIF) { $image = imagecreatefromgif($source); }
elseif (exif_imagetype($source) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) { $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); }
elseif (exif_imagetype($source) == IMAGETYPE_PNG) { $image = imagecreatefrompng($source); }

    return imagewebp($image, $destination, $quality);
}
```

I hope it will solve :-)