# how to fix message "Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference"

Tags: php

i do not know how to fix this message that appears on line with $newfilename = uniqid() ... :

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "zip", "html", "htm",  "js", "css", "less", "txt", "php");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

// skipped

echo // here the echo's

$newfilename = uniqid().".".end(explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]));
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" .     $newfilename);
  // het pad naar het bestand dat geupload is; ervan uitgaande dat de map uploads in de root staat
  echo 'Url: ' . '<b>http://www.jouwwebsite.nl/uploads/' .    $newfilename.'</b>';
  echo '<br /><br />';
}
// skipped...
```

Comment: Split it into two lines: `$data = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]); $newfilename = uniqid().".".end($data);`

Comment: But there is a better function for extracting the extension from a filename: [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) with the `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` flag: `$newfilename = uniqid().".".pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: Or in this case perhaps: [How to get the file extension in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10368217) (Still may not be advisable to use as unfiltered source for a target filename extension.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Message is gone!