# Unique file name after uploading

Tags: php

I'm trying to rename a image after uploading it.
I want it to be a unique name.

I have this class (found on the internet):

http://pastebin.com/qQmC256A

I tried editing the file like this:

```
$upload_image = $target_path.basename($fileName);
```

to

```
$upload_image = $target_path.basename(uniqid($fileName, rand()));
```

but it gives me just a file, without an extension..

Comment: And? Sounds like it's working to me?

Comment: yeah, it is working. but it just gives me a file without the extension. how can I check what extension the image has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What else should happen? `uniqid` will generate something like:

```
php > echo uniqid('kittens.jpg', rand());
kittens.jpg57b72004c1a470.87520799
php > echo basename(uniqid('kittens.jpg', rand()));
kittens.jpg57b7201cdce2e9.40812361
```

You don't get a extension, because you turned the file's extension into part of the "middle" of the filename.

Perhaps something like this would work better:

```
$info = pathinfo($file);
$file = $path . $info['filename'] . uniqid() . $info['extension'];
```

Comment: thanks, this is working. I just had to add a "." after uniqid().

Answer (score 0):

On line 26 of the library you provided there's a variable named `$file_ext` that contain exactly what you need. Just concat it to the `$upload_image` so line 32 becomes:

`$upload_image = $target_path.basename(uniqid($fileName, rand())).$file_ext;`

Even if, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368236/4804390), I would get the extension in this way:

`$path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Because if the file name is, for example, `test.tar.gz` it will take only `.gz` as extension.

If you want to use this method, you could substitute line 22-24 with the above code.