# How to change image name to current time stamp php?

Tags: php, html, image

I want to change image name with current time stamp in php. 
My code are below :

```
$logo = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

$logo = image1.jpg
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../timeTableImg/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

i get image name in $logo. But Actually i want

```
$logo = 1484900616.jpg 

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../timeTableImg/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

file name may be dynamic. its may be jpg , png, jpeg. Also want to move file with new name.

Comment: why not just override the `$logo` with the timestamp you want.

Comment: and extension of image ??? its may be jpg or png

Comment: use the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368217/how-to-get-the-file-extension-in-php `$path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: its not my answer. i want something different. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
$path = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$logo = time().'.'.$ext;
```

And to use the new name. put this.

```js
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../timeTableImg/' . $logo);
```

Comment: i can't get .(dot) in file name. 1484984081jpg

Comment: just insert it in between. `$logo = time().'.'.$ext`

Comment: and i save image with old name. i want move image with new name in my folder

Answer (score 0):

Use move_uploaded_file function.

Example:

```
$file_path = "uploads/";   
$newfile = date('m-d-Y_H:i:s')'.jpg';
$filename = $file_path.$newfile;
if(!file_exists($filename))
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$filename))
    {
    // Other codes
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'file already exists';
}
```

Comment: i already use but i want to change file name with timestamp and than i used it.