# Apply a php code on a set of uploaded files

Tags: php, html

I've a php code that extract some information from a .dat file uploaded by the user. Now i want to apply this treatment on a set of uploaded file. so the user can choose a set of file when he click upload the treatment has to be done on each file.
i've tried this but it's not working :

```
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label>Selectionner le fichier .dat</label>
      <input type="file" name="excel" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="import" class="btn btn-info" value="Import" />
     </form>
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: yes it will naturally won't work, you'll need actual PHP codes, first process the form, usually its under `$_FILES`, since you're expecting multiple files add `[]` in the name attribute. this link can give you an idea https://thedebuggers.com/multiple-files-upload-using-html-php/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the file extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368217/how-to-get-the-file-extension-in-php)

Comment: what do you need exactly? multiple uploads?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php Example #1 Uploading multiple files

Comment: what php code? You need to tell us the whole story. At the moment its very unclear what youre asking.

Comment: the user upload a set of files : the PHP code extract some information from each file and store it in the database. this is the whole story nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let the user select multiple files you have to use the `multiple` attribute and add brackets `[]` to the name of the input.

You can do this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label>Selectionner le fichier .dat</label>
      <input type="file" name="excel[]" multiple />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="import" class="btn btn-info" value="Import" />
</form>
```

Then you can parse the `$_FILES` array and you will find all the uploaded files, for example:

```
Array
(
    [excel] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => img1.PNG
                    [1] => img2.PNG
                    [2] => img3.jpg
                    [3] => img4.png
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                    [1] => image/png
                    [2] => image/jpeg
                    [3] => image/png
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpWh5NRz
                    [1] => /tmp/php6KEOer
                    [2] => /tmp/phprLvUBi
                    [3] => /tmp/phplTP0Y9
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 63515
                    [1] => 54484
                    [2] => 14001
                    [3] => 84938
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: i have got a new problem :  Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Take a look at [max_file_uploads](http://php.net/manual/it/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads)